# Flutter align text to the width of the text above

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to align the small text so it is flush with the right edge of the larger text above but `TextAlign` is ignored unless you add a width in `Container` around the individual text widget.

```
Container(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text('One', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40)),
      Text('Two', textAlign: TextAlign.right, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
    ],
  ),
),
```

> I can't set a width since then it will not be the same for different devices. It should simply align right based on the width of the larger text above but it doesn't.

A width value should not be necessary since the width should be set by the width of the larger text, but without a width value `TextAlign` is ignored for some strange reason.

[image]

I need it to look like this:

[image]

Comment: tried `crossAxisAlignment` maybe?

Comment: @pskink To do what though? I'm using `TextAlign` for alignment. `crossAxisAlignment` sets the alignment for the whole column but I only want the lower text to be aligned to the right.

Comment: `"To do what though?"` tried: `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,`?

Comment: @pskink `crossAxisAlignment` sets the alignment for the whole column but I only want the lower text to be aligned to the right. That's what `TextAlign` is for, which I'm using but it doesn't work properly. I think it's probably a bug.

Comment: `Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
  children: <Widget>[
    Text('the title', textScaleFactor: 3.0,),
    Text('small', textScaleFactor: 1.0,),
  ],
),` - this gives exactly the output you need

Comment: @pskink That does seem to work with just two pieces of text. But what if there's another piece of text underneath that needs to be aligned to the left?

Comment: @pskink Also with `letterSpacing` which I'm using in my actual code, the text underneath is not flush. With `letterSpacing` off it shows ok though.

Comment: @pskink That doesn't work, it aligns to the width of the whole container and not the width of the large text above. Also it wouldn't make sense to use an `Align` widget when the `Text` widget has an alignment property...it seems a lot like a bug tbh.

Comment: yes it works, i checked that with left, center and right alignment

Comment: @pskink I checked it, it doesn't work. It aligns to the width of the container, like I said above, not to the width of the top text. Check my screenshots above which show the whole width of the container.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199140/discussion-between-hasen-and-pskink).

Comment: @pskink Let's continue this discussion in comments. Not sure why you're saying it works when I already checked it and it doesn't. You haven't explained what you're doing that makes it work.

Comment: like in answer below you need an `IntrinsicWidth` - for example: `IntrinsicWidth(
  child: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
  Align(alignment: Alignment.centerRight, child: Text('foo', textScaleFactor: 2.0,)),
  Align(alignment: Alignment.centerRight, child: Text('small',)),
  Align(alignment: Alignment.center, child: Text('foo bar', textScaleFactor: 2.0,)),
  Align(alignment: Alignment.center, child: Text('small',)),
  Align(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, child: Text('foo bar spam', textScaleFactor: 2.0,)),
  Align(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, child: Text('small',)),
],
),
),`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can combine `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` for Column widget and [IntrinsicWidth](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicWidth-class.html) widget. IntrinsicWidth

> Sizes its child's width to the child's maximum intrinsic width.

```
Center(
  child: 
     Container(
        child:
            IntrinsicWidth(
               child: 
                  Column(
                     crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                         children: <Widget>[
                            Text('The title', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40)),
                            Text('small', textAlign: TextAlign.right, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
                         ],
        )))
```

It looks like this
[image]

---

PS Perhaps you dont need Container widget here

Comment: Aha! Wow that's the true answer. This actually makes the mysterious `TextAlign` do something for once. Adding  another line of text underneath aligned left works also. Good work indeed sir.